# Derelict spacecraft with oddly shaped doorways opened by enduring shock

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

I remember seeing a movie that came out in the late 50s or early 60s and used to frequently air late at night long before cable was around. Astronauts on some planet find a derelict spacecraft. They go inside and notice the "doorways" were oddly shaped. I remember thinking that these doorways were shaped similar to the Krell doorways in Forbidden Planet.

Anyway, they walk into a room and the door closes behind them. They try to open the door, but can't. They notice a console in the middle of the room. Here I am even more fuzzy, as there is either a button that has to be held down or a three-finger depression that one of the astronauts puts his hand in. Either way, he receives a severe shock and he pulls his hand away. But they notice the door budged slightly. The astronaut has to hold his hand onto the button or in the hand depression and endure the shock for a longer period of time for the door to open all the way. This is all I got on this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241253/movie-involving-body-snatching-might-be-an-early-1950s-variant-of-the-thing (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Planet of the Vampires?
The button is found on the console but it's not attached and gives a shock when touched.
[image]

The relevant scene can be seen at 54:37